# How do I move folders recursively?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do something like this to remove spaces from all directories and sub-directories. Here is the code I have;

```
find /var/www/ -name "*" -type d | while read dir; do
  mv "$dir" `echo "$dir" | tr ' ' '.'`;
done
```

This works but only per each directory at one time. It does not work on sub-directories, unless I re-run the script multiple times. If you guys know a better way of doing this so it will work on sub-directories too, please let me know.

Between, when I run this script it turns directory such as "This is directory one" for example into "This.is.directory.one". But sub-directories with spaced folder names does not change unless I re-run the script multiple times like I said.

Comment: This is the problem Chris, because mv does not have one :-)

Comment: that's why I said recursive **function**.  Functions are a `bash` feature, not `mv` feature. Still, depth-first search is a better solution. Functions would be slower in all probability. Still, investigate them if you don't know about them - they can be useful. `:(){ :|: & };:` (don't run that!)

Answer (score 1):

This ought to work correctly.

```
find . -depth -type d -name '* *' -exec bash -c 'dir="${1%%/}";d1="${dir%/*}";d2="${dir##*/}";mv "$1" "$d1/${d2// /.}"' -- {} \;
```

We're doing depth-first searching, meaning that directory contents get processed before the directory they're in. We're including only directories with spaces in the name. Then we have a little bash routine which, using parameter substitution, chops the trailing slash off of the path, splits the path in to two parts (the directory name (d2) and the path to that directory (d1)), then mv's the original full path and name to the same path but with spaces in the name replaced by a periods.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Sorpigal's answer, but slightly simpler due to the use of `-execdir`:

```
find . -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -name "* *" -execdir bash -c 'old="{}"; new=${old// /.}; mv "${old##*/}" "$new"' \;
```

Comment: Nice, I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
find ~/my/path -type f -name "*(J)*.*" -exec mv {} ~/my/path/j \;
```

from 
https://superuser.com/questions/103151/recursive-move-files-of-specific-type-to-a-specific-path

Comment: Could you reformat the code block, please? It just needs 4 leading spaces instead of blockquote.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

you should put "depth" flag for your find command: it causes find(1) to perform a depth first traversal. In *FreeBSD* it is **-d**. Sorry, I don't remember name for same in Linux distributions, check **find(1)** for details.

```
find -d $dir -type d|  while read dir; do
  mv "$dir" `echo "$dir" | tr ' ' '.'`;
done
```

Comment: GNU find supports `-d` for compatibility and `-depth` normally.